# Append number to end of url string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, url, append

I have the below for loop which I use to append a number to the end of a URL String:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    PUT_URL = PUT_URL + i;
    System.out.println(PUT_URL);
    sendPUT();
    System.out.println("PUT Done");
}
```

Currently the url appears in the format:

```
myurl1
myurl12
myurl123
myurl1234    
myurl12345
```

What's the best way to amend this so the url appears as?

```
myurl1
myurl2
myurl3
myurl4
myurl5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line

```
PUT_URL = PUT_URL + i;
```

you are modifying `PUT_URL`, that I presume contains `myurl`, by appending `i` to it and then printing. Therefore in the next iteration `PUT_URL` will contain a number at the end and then you are appending the next number.

I would suggest creating a constant with the prefix of a url without the number at the end and then append a number to that to create `PUT_URL`:

```
String URL_PREFIX = "myurl";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    PUT_URL = URL_PREFIX + i + 1;
    System.out.println(PUT_URL);
    sendPUT();
    System.out.println("PUT Done");
}
```

Comment: lol that's correct I suppose but not exactly what I'm after. I want a URL with the appended numbers. 
    System.out.println(PUT_URL + i); 
was just for my testing.

Should I just create a new variable which I assign 
    PUT_URL + i 
to or is there a better way?

Comment: Modified my answer accordingly

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help.